# Override android gradle versionCode form command line

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have a build.gradle file in my android app with this settings:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "some.app.id"
        versionName '1.2'
        versionCode 3
        ...
    }
...
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml **does not** contain versionCode and not contain versionName.

Now i want to build this app on Jenkins and pass BUILD_NUMBER as a versionCode for app, so that every build has a higher version.

So in job I hava a call:

```
./gradlew -PversionCode=$BUILD_NUMBER clean build
```

When i use "versionCode" to rename "app-release.apk" value of versionCode is the same as passed from command line:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release.apk", "MyApp_" + "_v" + versionName + "." + versionCode + ".apk"))
    }
}
```

**Summary**

So I have a default value of "versionCode" set to 3, but when building on Jenkins I want to override it from command line.

**The problem**

The problem is that in AndroidManifest inside build .apk app has versionCode set to 3 instead of value from BUILD_NUMBER.
I checked it with "aapt dump badging"

**The question**

Can this value "versionCode" from android defaultConfig be overriden by command line parameter?

I know, I could use a function as explained in:
http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2013/gradle-android-inject-version-code-from-command-line-parameter/ 
but I prefer the cleaner way of simple override but I cant get it working.

Comment: @Selvin I'm posting on StackOverflow after 2 days of searching and trying different versions of parameters, so I did some of my homework :)
If no one uses versionCode as I described, then maybe it wont work.
But I'm looking to someone who tried this and maybe have more luck than I have.

Comment: ... and ? I didn't say that you did not search .. link looks nice and, in your shoes, I would use it ... i just point you that it is not the same variable ... the one from the command line is a project variable and android.defaultConfig.versionCode is in a different class ... did you tried `versionCode versionCode` or `versionCode project.versionCode` ?

Comment: @Selvin FYI I've edited my first comment.
For me it is strange that inside "applicationVariants" the "versionCode" value is same as BUILD_NUMBER, but in defaultConfig the value it is different.
Are you saing that those two "versionCode" could be NOT the same variables?
Can they refer to different fields in different objects??

Comment: yeah, i'm doing some test(my solution will not work) ... *could be NOT the same variables?* => fields in a different objects

Comment: you can use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/4b8213d789c88dd7a279) but i don't think if it is cleaner ... then `gradlew -PversionCode=6 -PversionName=3.0 build` ...

Comment: Currently I have
`versionCode project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? project.versionCode.toInteger() : 3`
It works but it doesnt look as clean as code from question ;)

Comment: [function from the link with defaults ...](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/47792b03b83ada3557f4) but it's only a matter of taste ...

Comment: @Selvin Tnx for your help, if you paste code from one of your gists as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use properties by defining them in a `gradle.properties` file, see [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties). 
But you'll have to be really careful which names you use for your properties: if you use versionName that property will have the correct value in gradle (you can `println` it) but it won't end up in your AndroidManifest.xml! So I chose to use 'versName'. (I don't know enough about gradle to understand why this is so...)

So in your project's `gradle.properties` you can define the following properties:

`versCode=3
versName=1.2`

And then change the `build.gradle` file into:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "some.app.id"
        versionName versName
        versionCode versCode as Integer
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can override them on the command line like this: `./gradlew -PversCode=4 -PversName=2.1.3 clean build`

Comment: FYI I needed versionCode versCode as Integer, otherwise got an exception  complaining about method versionCode() not found.

Comment: That is good to know, that you can override properties from gradle.properties file.